# Can I still use the "none" bytecode provider in Hibernate 6.3.1?

Tags: hibernate

I weave my entities at build time and consequently have no need of a bytecode provider in Hibernate.

I've noticed that as of version 6.3.1 (possibly earlier?) if I set the bytecode provider to `none`, its `getReflectionOptimizer` method, encountered, apparently, during the normal usage of Hibernate, and out of my control since I cannot use the now-removed `use_reflection_optimizer` setting, now throws an exception instead of (presumably) not returning a `ReflectionOptimizer`.

So it would seem that the `none` bytecode provider is now useless.  Is that true?